# hash algorithm to produce a nice key from a messy value

Tags: hash

I'm looking for an algorithm which given a messy value (like a url with a querystring) produces a value which can be used as a key.

Ideally, it should have a fairly low collision rate, produce a value which is shorter than the input, be made of alphanumerics (a-z 1-9), and create the same output given the same input (though not necessarily reversible).

Anything come to mind?

Comment: You could use this blog post as a hint http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/08/url-shortening-hashes-in-practice.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several excellent examples exist as industry standards, such as [SHA-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) and [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5). There will be a library for running either of these any language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

MD5 or or the SHA functions are fine (however, MD5 is less secure in terms of collision rate, I'd suggest SHA1, or the best, but longest SHA512).

They're implemented in OpenSSL for C, or CommonCrypto in Objective-C, etc.

You might also consider using CRC64 as a hash function, because it has a really small footprint and a rather good collision rate -- compared to its length, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a lot. MD5, SHA-1, SHA-128, SHA-256,...

If say... MD5's 32 character are to long for you, use substring and just take the first x characters.

Of course there are many other solutions like CRC32 that you could use, but it's hard to say what will be good for your use case without knowing what your goal is...